# Rails conditionally validate field if created by form and not REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that receives new workorders from another application via the REST interface.  Users can also input new workorders via a form.

If the new workorder is created via the new form, I want to validate that the user has selected a value from a checkbox (pick list) for Supervisor.

I don't want to validate, if the user updates the Workorder or the Workorder is created using the REST interface.

This would work so that it's validated during create and not update:

```
validate_presence_of :supervisor, :on => :create
```

But, how would I make it not validate when the record is created via REST?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would you skip validation for the REST interface?

Comment: Because it's ok if workorders come from the app we are integrating with, but not by users entering new workorders.  Business rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Model

```
attr_accessor :rest

validates_presence_of :supervisor, :on => :create, :if => lambda{ |model| model.rest }
```

## Controller

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    model.rest = true
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  But, I'm using RABL to create the JSON for the workorder. So, the workorder controller doesn't have the `format.json` in it. How would I set `model.rest = true` ?

Comment: You can use request.format, but I think you should not rely on format to know when to respond or not. I suppose you will provide authentication to your order creator application, i.e. and application id and application secret.

Comment: You could handle authentication with a new model that saves application ids and secrets, is better to go with model at once even if you have just one application, because it will allow you to scale in the future.

Comment: you can simplify that to `:if => :rest?`

Comment: How would be that? because `rest?` is not a method for a model.